# Use angular material design theme on bootstrap project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I already have a project created using Twitter Bootstrap but i want to control the colours of the theme as shown [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/01_introduction), is it possible to achieve the same thing in bootstrap using the `$mdThemingProvider`?

Comment: No you cannot use $mdthemingprovider for bootstrap

Comment: You can change the respetive SASS/LESS variables of bootstrap and recompile the CSS

Comment: i want dynamic changes.